# Returning a reference to an object pointed through its interface

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, abstract-class, unique-ptr

I'm building a small framework in C++ which contains objects which are stored in an STL container as `unique_ptr` to their interface. I thought `unique_ptr` was the best choice as the container is supposed to be the sole owner of the objects.

I wanted to retrieve a reference to the pointed object from the container to pass to the caller. But when I get the pointer I need to dereference it to pass a reference of the content from my function which of course doesn't work on an abstract class.

I do not want to pass the raw pointer which would defy the whole concept I was developing.
I cannot cast as I cannot know the concrete type of the stored object.
The only solution it came to my mind which is reasonable enough is to store a shared pointer in the container and pass a weak pointer to the caller but if you know some other way to obtain the same result it would be great.

This is a basic code structure, with `Base` being an abstract class:

```
class Container
{
    vector<unique_ptr<Base>> m_C;

public:
    Base& GetBase(int index)
    {
        return *(m_C.at(index)); //This do not compile as Base is abstract
    }
};
```

**EDIT**:

I'm not sure what more do you need as an example. The main will look like this

```
int main() {
Container X;
// Fill X here
A tmp = X.get(10) // Let's say I want the tenth element
}
```

Compiling on OSX with clang I get this error

```
variable type 'MXIO::MXEvent' is an abstract class
```

**EDIT2: Problem solved**

I solved the issue. The problem was not in the way the function was returning but in the way I was catching the return. I was using

```
auto tmp = X.get(10)
```

Assuming auto would take care of taking the reference while I should have been using

```
auto&& tmp = X.get(10)
```

Comment: You _can_ have a reference to an abstract class. What error message do you get?

Comment: "This do not compile". [Are you sure?](http://ideone.com/fwNSnw) Please provide a complete reproducible example.

Comment: A raw pointer is fine for someone just using a class or interface. So long as you know the lifetime (of the object) will be longer than the raw pointer will be used.

Comment: @RichardCritten Sure, but if you don't need to be able to return null, a reference should be fine also.

Comment: Hi chris
I know I can have references to abstract classes but to return it from my function I have to dereference the pointer or at least I do not know any other method, that's why I'm asking

Comment: And what is the problem with dereferencing the pointer?

Comment: I edited the question with the solution.
Maybe due to the fact it was 4AM I misunderstood the error the first time I read it and I didn't get it was actually a problem with the catching of the reference from the function. I still have to understand properly the subtleties of the auto contruct

Comment: I would suggest that you post your solution as an answer and not as an edit:  it will be clear for everybody that the problem is solved and the answer can help other readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your interesting design works perfectly well !**

Using the example as you displayed it, and using a simple `Base`:

- the `Container` code compiled without any error;
- the calling code compiled also without any error.

So the error is not reproductible with your snippet. And your design works as intended.

**Real problem unrelated to your design**

Looking at the error message, the problem appears to be very different and not related at all to the `unique_ptr`.  I

If `MXIO::MXEvent` is `Base`, the message says that `Base`is an abstract class. In fact, when adding a pure virtual function to my simple `Base`, I managed to reproduce your error message:

```
Base tmp =  X.get(10);   // tmp should be a full tmp object copy constructed from returned value
                         // But we CANNOT instantiate an abstract object !!
```

Note that fortunately your base class is abstract and you got an error message.  With a concrete base class it would have compiled well but the object would have been [sliced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) !

If you don't want to loose polymorphism of your abstract class you have to make `tmp` a reference:

```
Base &c = test.GetBase(4);   // here the reference is copied and no new object is instantiated. 
                             // c still reffers to the original concrete derived object.
```

Note that while `auto&&` works well, `Base&&` doesn't because a reference is returned.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Christophe I will post the solution of the problem I had as an answer:

The problem was not in the way the function was returning its result but in the way I was catching the result.

```
int main() {
Container X;
// Fill X here
A tmp = X.get(10) // Let's say I want the tenth element
}
```

As Christophe pointed out the problem with this code is that tmp is not a reference to the returned object but a concrete object which of course cannot be instantiated as the base class is abstract.

In this case one should catch the return itself by reference

```
int main() {
Container X;
// Fill X here
A& tmp = X.get(10) // Let's say I want the tenth element
}
```